# Counting how many different words have exactly the letter 'o' twice

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm new at ApacheSpark. Currently, I'm performing some statistical analysis for a text. I start reading the text and storing it in a variable as follows:

```
loremRDD = sc.textFile(fileName, 8).map(removePunctuation).filter(lambda x: len(x)>0)
#First 10 lines
loremRDD.take(10)
```

The result is a `PythonRDD[66] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53` variable. Below there are the first 10 lines of the text:

```
['aut minima deleniti et autem minus illo esse dolores eligendi corrupti dolore minima nostrum eos nobis nam nihil aspernatur nam ut quae sint laborum ut dolores error possimus aperiam consequatur',
 'pariatur sed quo non itaque qui pariatur saepe ad quis consequatur nihil iste molestias et eos ut expedita vel reiciendis dolorem enim doloribus quam architecto aperiam',
 'sed repudiandae pariatur similique est aut sequi animi in aperiam enim ipsa enim dolorem inventore aut quo odio in consequatur et',
 'aspernatur ad esse et aliquid itaque dolores rerum quia commodi explicabo non magnam nostrum consectetur non sint eum nulla et aut quis doloribus itaque nulla molestiae quis est est quo facilis incidunt a ipsa in itaque sed aut nobis facere dignissimos atque unde cum ea vero',
 'tenetur vel quod voluptatum laudantium dolores neque aut est modi qui aperiam itaque aperiam quae ratione doloremque aut delectus quas qui',
 'qui placeat vel ipsam praesentium sint recusandae dicta minus praesentium omnis sequi a sed veritatis porro ab et officia esse commodi pariatur sequi cumque',
 'mollitia facilis amet deleniti quia laborum commodi et molestias maxime quia dignissimos inventore neque libero deleniti ad quo corrupti numquam quis accusantium',
 'architecto harum sunt et enim nisi commodi et id reprehenderit illum molestias illo facilis fuga eum illum quasi fugit qui',
 'modi voluptatem quia et saepe inventore sed quo ea debitis explicabo vel perferendis commodi exercitationem sequi eum dolor cupiditate ab molestiae nemo ullam neque hic ipsa cupiditate dolor molestiae neque nam nobis nihil mollitia unde',
 'voluptates quod in ipsum dicta fuga voluptatibus sint consequatur quod optio molestias nostrum repellendus consequatur aliquam fugiat provident omnis minus est quisquam exercitationem eum voluptas fugit quae eveniet perspiciatis assumenda maxime']
```

I need to know how many different words have twice the letter 'o'. For example, the word dolorem has twice the letter 'o'.

At the moment, I´ve created `distintWordsRDD` which stores all differents words contained in the text as follows:

```
loremWordsRDD = loremRDD.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))

distintWordsMapRDD = loremWordsRDD.map(lambda word: (word,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
            
distintWordsRDD=distintWordsMapRDD.keys().distinct()
# Showing 8 first words
print(distintWordsRDD.take(8))
```

The result of the 8 first words is:

```
['tempora', 'sapiente', 'vitae', 'nisi', 'quidem', 'consectetur', 'perferendis', 'debitis']
```

My problem is that I don´t know how to retrieve from `distintWordsRDD` a list with the words that have two 'o'.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
your_text=''.join(your_original_list_of_texts)
result=[i for i in your_text.split() if i.count('o')==2]
print(result)

['dolores', 'dolore', 'dolores', 'dolorem', 'doloribus', 'dolorem', 'odio']
```

However the text that you provided is split to many subtexts ('sometext1', 'sometext2', 'sometext3, etc) and it needs some additional work so that it will come to a simple text format ('alltext')
If you provide exact details of your input text, i will adjust the code so that it will work properly with the input without additional manual work

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post showing more details. Please, note that when doing your proposed solution the following error is displayed: AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I edited my code. The first line changes your original list of texts to a simple text. The rest of the code will look for words with 2 'o' Let me know if it works ok

Comment: Have you considered that this is a RDD object? Even though I can put here the text, u have to consider that this is a RDD object and RDD objects are not iterable. Furthermore, words need to be unique cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one string `sentence`:

```
results = set(word for word in sentence.split() if word.count('o') == 2)
```

If you have a list `sentences` of strings (which is what you show in your question):

```
results = set(
    word
    for sentence in sentences
    for word in sentence.split()
    if word.count('o') == 2
)
```

I'm using `set` to unify the results.

Output for the list of sentences in your example:

```
{'odio', 'dolorem', 'dolore', 'doloremque', 'dolor', 'doloribus', 'optio', 'commodi', 'porro', 'dolores'}
```

If you need a list then just convert the `set` in a `list`: `results = list(results))`.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post showing more details. Please, note that when doing your proposed solution the following error is displayed: AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Panri93 Sure, `split` is a `string` method. But that wasn't quite your question, was it? You have to convert the content you're receiving into a list of strings, just like the one above in your 2. code block, and then do the stuff @IoaTzimas or I proposed.

Comment: Hi Timus, thanks for your reply. The exercise says 'how many different words' if I do what you are saying I'll be getting repeated words as shown in the result produced by @IoaTzimas (see 'dolores' twice but is the same word). That´s why I computed the distintWordsRDD to avoid the repetition of words.

Comment: @Panri93 I don't understand: When I try my code (2. block) with your list of sentences above then I only get dolores _once_? That's why I used `set`. Output I get: `{'optio', 'doloremque', 'dolore', 'dolorem', 'commodi', 'odio', 'doloribus', 'dolores', 'dolor', 'porro'}`.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I'm still not getting the result! I have the variable loremRDD which contains the list of sentences. If I go to your 2nd block of code and I replace 'sentences' by loremRDD it displays me the error of ''TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem doing the following:

```
results = distintWordsRDD.filter(lambda word: word.count('o')==2)
print (results.collect())
print(results.count())
```

Result:

```
['porro', 'odio', 'laboriosam', 'doloremque', 'doloribus', 'dolores', 'dolor', 'corporis', 'commodi', 'optio', 'dolorum', 'dolore', 'dolorem']
13
```

Comment: Neat. I realise now that this was more about `pyspark` than _pure_ python. I hadn't looked at this angle of the question.